# Ping IPv6 address in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ping, ipv6

Is there any convenient way to ping an IPv6 address in Unity C#? Something like this:

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

public class Test : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Awake()
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = ping.Send("::1", 5000);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"reply {reply.Address} {reply.Status}");
    }
}
```

I have searched and read the [Ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-5.0) here, but the function doesn't work.

---

**Edit:**
Sorry everyone, I thought it was a C# question since I use System.Net. I was completely wrong. It seems the problem only happens in Unity C# after I tried the same function in a console app in Visual Studio. I will change the question a bit.

---

- My Unity version: 2019.4.24f1
- Scripting Backend: IL2CPP
- Api Compatility Level: .NET 4.x

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `Ping` class has overloads which use the `IPAddress`, and the `IPAddress` type supports IPv6. What part of that isn't working for you? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Ping.Send() takes an IP address object, which can certainly accept an IPv6 value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=net-5.0.  It should also accept the "compressed form": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/ipv6-addressing

Comment: Just to re-enforce what @PeterDuniho and @paulsm4 stated, try using an actual **`IPAddress`** *object* instead of passing a string. It has the added bonus of avoiding formatting issues with using strings, such as transposing information.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I thought it was a C# question since I use System.Net. I was completely wrong. It seems the problem only happens in Unity after I tried the same function in a console app in Visual Studio. I will change the question a bit.

Comment: Which version of Unity, and which version of dotNET? (see Player Settings/Other/Configuration/Runtime Version, and Player Settings/Other/Configuration/API Compatibility) If not ".NET 4.x", try that instead.

Comment: @Immersive It's .NET 4.x, I've tried other option .NET standard 2.0 and it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1):

```
Send(IPAddress, Int32, Byte[], PingOptions)
```

please look overload of IPAddress 
System.Net.IPAddress class is supported also IPv6 
so you want to make IPAddress object of like IPv6

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a C# question since I use System.Net. I was completely wrong. It seems the problem only happens in Unity C# after I tried the same function in a console app in Visual Studio. I will change the question a bit.